# Changing the weights of each tree in a random forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently working on random forests under scikit-learn.

Is there a possible way to change the weights of each estimator used in the random forest generated?

Comment: Hi NWgs, welcome to StackOverflow! In order to help other from the SO community to answer your question, the best is to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way, others can point out what is wrong with your code. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to see how to ask a better question. Cheers :)

Comment: Hi NWgs, is there a reason why you'd want to do this? Depending on your problem, it may be better to get help from the statistics community: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> Are you asking how to change the weights of each estimator
>   individually or how to change the answer weight of each tree in the
>   voting system when doing `predict()`?

When you have a fitted random forest, the parameter estimators_ returns an array of decision trees, and all of them can be edited individually, f.e:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, True], [2, False]])

model.fit(df[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1), df[1])

print(model.estimators_)
```

Outputs:

```
[DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                    max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
                    min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                    min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                    random_state=1942352063, splitter='best'),
 DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                        max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
                        min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                        random_state=1414900336, splitter='best')]
```

So you can select the first one just using `model.estimators_[0]`.

Then, if you read the [Decision tree docu](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html), you can change the [feature_importances_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.feature_importances_).

If your question is how to change the random forest voting system, then I recommend you take a [look at the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L591), but let me tell you that it's not a good decision to *modify* this feature.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.py#L625), random forest takes for each output the biggest probability (of all trees), so you could work with the prediction probability of each decision tree individually.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. And yes, I am currently testing something on the weights of the random forests generated to see if it outperforms the built-in generator for the weights or not.

I'll get into the code as you suggested then.

Comment: I am looking for a python/scikit learn related or similar function as the one in MATLAB: [TreeBagger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.html). You can customize the creation of trees on this class. Is [BaggingClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier) similar to this?